# Is this identity known and if so, does it have a name?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, factorial, products

$$\frac{a!}{b!} = 
\begin{cases} 
\prod_{k=0}^{a-b-1} (a-k) &\ \ a > b \\
\\
1\div\prod_{k=0}^{b-a-1} (b-k) & \ \ a<b\\
\end{cases}$$

Furthermore, if it is known, does it hold any relevance?

Comment: I'm afraid it's too obvious to deserve a name. It's a simple consequence of the definition of factorial.

Comment: I think you should use parentheses around the $a-k$ in the capital pi notation. Otherwise it looks like the $-k$ is outside the product.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen Thanks for the feedback, will do so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is one way of expressing the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).